# Python for loop and if control

Tags: python

[Greetings, I'm trying to make a user login using a for loop, but when I use and in the if block I use to cancel the operation, even if I don't enter 0, the process ends, but when I use or it doesn't work, why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzFPM.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Questions should include a [mcve] in the body of the question, with your code and any errors as text, not as an image or link, so that we can better understand how to help

Answer (score 1):

Number 3 and string '3' are not equal

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUDb1.png)